# Show editor widgets only on pages that use a specific template?

Tags: widgets, editor

I am utilizing the following code to add an additional three Featured Images to homepages in a multisite installation:

```
if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) {
    new MultiPostThumbnails(
        array(
            'label' => 'Core Home Image 1',
            'id' => 'core-home-1',
            'post_type' => 'page'
        )
    );
    new MultiPostThumbnails(
        array(
            'label' => 'Core Home Image 2',
            'id' => 'core-home-2',
            'post_type' => 'page'
        )
    );
    new MultiPostThumbnails(
        array(
            'label' => 'Core Home Image 3',
            'id' => 'core-home-3',
            'post_type' => 'page'
        )
    );
}
```

The new edit page widgets are displaying and functioning as they should, however, they are appearing on all edit pages.  How do I force WordPress to only display them on the pages that use a specific template, i.e. Core Front Page Template (wp-content/themes/mytheme/templates/core-front-page.php)?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Try the conditional is_page_template('core-front-page.php') after the function.

Answer (score 0):

Solution used:

```
// decide to show or hide the widgets
function check_for_using_template(selected){
    if (selected == "page-templates/core-front-page.php"){
        jQuery("#page-core-home-1").show();
        jQuery("#page-core-home-2").show();
        jQuery("#page-core-home-3").show();
        jQuery("label[for='page-core-home-1-hide']").show();
        jQuery("label[for='page-core-home-2-hide']").show();
        jQuery("label[for='page-core-home-3-hide']").show();
    }else{
        jQuery("#page-core-home-1").hide();
        jQuery("#page-core-home-2").hide();
        jQuery("#page-core-home-3").hide();
        jQuery("label[for='page-core-home-1-hide']").hide();
        jQuery("label[for='page-core-home-2-hide']").hide();
        jQuery("label[for='page-core-home-3-hide']").hide();
    }
}
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    check_for_using_template(jQuery("#page_template").val());
    jQuery("#page_template").change(function(){
        check_for_using_template(jQuery("#page_template").val());
    })
});
```

Unfortunately, I was unable to successfully utilized the is_page_template, so I used jQuery.  Works, though it may not be the most efficient solution.